# Extend Express JS router TypeScript definition for “named-routes”

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, named-routing

We're using an extension called [named-routes](https://github.com/alubbe/named-routes) with Express which has served us quite well in the past. Now that we’re gradually TypeScript-ifying our codebase, we are facing following issue: The module extends Express’ router object, so that routes can have an identifier:

```
router.get('/admin/user/:id', 'admin.user.edit', (req, res, next) => …
```

The Express typings are of course not aware of the this optional identifier and report a compile error. I followed the instructions from [“Module Augmentation”](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) and created the following `express-named-routes.d.ts`:

```
import { IRouterMatcher } from 'express';
import { PathParams, RequestHandlerParams } from 'express-serve-static-core';

declare module 'express' {
  export interface IRouterMatcher<T> {
    // copied from existing decl. and added the `name` argument
    (path: PathParams, name: string, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
    (path: PathParams, name: string, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
  }
}
```

And of course imported it in the corresponding file:

```
 import '../types/express-named-routes'
```

But this still gives me an `error TS2345: Argument of type '"my.route.name"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.`

Comment: Could you share your `express-named-routes.d.ts` or submit it to DefinitelyTyped?

Comment: @Forseti Yes, I will do. I'm currently on vacation until end of month, but I put myself a reminder. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: have a good vacation then :) I asked because for my the solution in answer isn't working and I wonder if I miss the bigger scope or something. I'm quite new to TypeScript so this is possible :)

Comment: @Forseti Managed to finished the typings -- feel free to have a look at the PR on DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/26403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it inside a module called 'named-routes' like this:

```
declare module 'named-routes' {
  import { IRouterMatcher } from 'express';
  import { PathParams, RequestHandler, RequestHandlerParams } from 'express-serve-static-core';

  module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    export interface IRouterMatcher<T> {
    // copied from existing decl. and added the `name` argument
      (path: PathParams, name: string, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
      (path: PathParams, name: string, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I’ve made the typings now available on DefinitelyTyped via [`@types/named-routes`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/named-routes).